# Transparent menu in divi theme with revolution slider for wordpress

Tags: wordpress, revolution-slider

I'm using the Divi theme and Revolution slider I want to make the menu bar transparent with the slider behind it, i used the fullwidth code widget. If I make the menu bar transparent, it just shows up as white above the slider, no overlap.

Here's the code i used which is correct:

```css
.et_fullwidth_nav #main-header .container {
    background: transparent;
}
```

Heres the site: abdul.joyofhuman.com

Answer (score 0):

within the section of the Divi, you can use a negative margin ...